# No symbol table info available + segmentation fault

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, codeblocks, bgi

I'm trying to run a simple graphics program with Code::Blocks. I am able to build it without errors but when I run it I get an error message, `No symbol table info available` and segmentation fault. Here is my code:

```
#include <graphics.h> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   initwindow(800,600);
   circle(200,300,600);
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

And here is my build output:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in aa (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -o alla.exe -Wall -g  -c E:\C++\aa\main.cpp -o     obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\aa.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -    luuid -loleaut32 -lole32  -lbgi
Output file is bin\Debug\aa.exe with size 1.02 MB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is `graphics.h`?

Comment: Is `graphics.h` from [Borland Graphics Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Graphics_Interface)? Thats what google points me to. Don't you think that is a tiny bit outdated? Or am I missing something? Can somebody please clear this up?

Comment: Wow:  question asked on CodeBlocks forum:http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=13046.0;prev_next=prev

Comment: The last BGI update was 1997. Seventeen years is a long time.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews http://winbgim.codecutter.org/ >> Nov 2005 update,

Comment: @Nabla I've `graphics.h` from the site above